# Does javascript have an optional indexing operator?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I have:

```
let a = { b: { c1: { z: false } } }
```

Other times I have:

```
let a = { b: { c2: { z: false } } }
```

I have `let n = 'c1'` or `let n = 'c2'`

I can do this to propagate the undefined:

```
a?.b[n]?.z
```

But other than `if(a.b) ...`, can I do anything shorthand if `b` is undefined?

There isn't a `?[` it seems, and I don't think I can do `a['b'][n]?.z` either, because if there is no b then attempting to index `n` on it will give *cannot read property VALUE_OF_N of undefined* ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
a?.b?.[n]?.z
```

The `?.` operator can be used before a `[ ]` expression. It looks odd, but `?.` is itself a complete token so it syntactically makes sense. In other words, `?.` normally isn't just a question mark before the usual `.` operator; it's an entire operator unto itself.

```js
let a;
let n;

a = { b: { c1: { z: false } } }
n = 'c1';

console.log(a?.b[n]?.z);

a = { b: { c2: { z: false } } }
n = 'c2';

console.log(a?.b?.[n]?.z);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I hadn't realized this because `a.[n]` is invalid, so I was thinking "`[` may not have anything before it" and I'd missed the "syntax" box on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining - i see it works for funcs too

Comment: @CaiusJard yea it's unexpected, but it would be even stranger if the feature change did not account for this situation.